# javascript base object to create 2 other objects with different methods

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I've been playing around with javascript for years, but I'm trying to get serious now.  Studying, and into Objects.

I want to create a base object, and use it to create 2 other objects that are slightly different.

I thought this would work :

```
function movingObject(x, y, z){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
}

var positiveMover = new movingObject(x, y, z);
positiveMover.prototype.move = function(a, b){
    yadda yadda
}

var negativeMover = new movingObject(x, y, z);
negativeMover.prototype.move = function(b, a){
    adday adday
}

var pic = postiveMover(1, 2, 3);
pic.move(20, 10);
```

I get a undefined error on the move.....pretty sure I've got the wrong idea. Any advice would be appreciated - links to information, or the right keywords to google

Comment: In javascript, `x.prototype` is not "the prototype of x".

Comment: I'm tyring to add the move function to the negativeMover object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is more like two classes, that you want to build :

```
function movingObject(x, y, z){
   this.x = x;       this.y = y;       this.z = z;
}

// positive mover : child class of movingObject    
function positiveMover (x, y, z) {  
    // use parent class's constructor.
    movingObject.apply(this,arguments); 
};

// inherit parent's class.
positiveMover.prototype = Object.create(movingObject.prototype); 

positiveMover.prototype.move = function(a, b){   yadda yadda    }
```

However, if you seek a per-instance choice of a method, you could do :

```
function movingObject(x, y, z, movingMethod){
   this.x = x;       this.y = y;       this.z = z;
   this.move = movingMethod;
}
```

Or just set the move property of a moving object, thus overriding the default prototype :

```
function movingObject(x, y, z){
   this.x = x;       this.y = y;       this.z = z;
}
movingObject.prototype.move= function(a,b) { /*some default code*/}

var oneMover = new movingObject(0,0,0);
oneMover.move = function(a,b) { /* some specific code */ };
```

Comment: Thanks GameAlchemist! Peer-instance choice is actually what I'm after, but I appreciate the lessons with the other 2 options as well